# OS X: Distribution to Mac App Store signing troubles

Tags: macos, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle, code-signing

I'm stuck with a problem, when I set Signing (General target's tab) to `Mac App Store`, it changes target's Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity to a `Mac Developer`.

And vice-versa if I set Code Signing Identity to `3rd Party Mac Developer Application:...` Xcode changes Signing (at the General tab) to `None`. Stuck with it, maybe someone encounter this? Thanks.

Achieving project as is doesn't allow me to Upload / Validate project.

I want to mention, also, that my goal is to upload the app to App Store (Mac of course). I also have helper application in my bundle, it have its own bundle ID.